# How can I get the files stored in host machine?

Tags: windows, linux, filesystems, vmware

I installed a Linux systems on a VMWare which is a guest of
Windows XP operating systems.

How can I get files stored in XP file systems directly when working in
Linux environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two ways:

1. [VMware Shared Folders](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html).  These are built in to VMware and work well but you need the [VMware tools](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/new_guest_tools_ws.html) installed and working on the guest OS.
2. Just share a folder in Windows and [mount it in the Linux guest using Samba](http://cri.ch/linux/docs/sk0001.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to the guest files from the host, there are user level tools provided by VMWare that allow you to mount VMWare virtual disks.

See: [VMWare Disk Mount [pdf]](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwareDiskMount.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Failing all that, you could use a generic file transfer utility like FTP or SCP :-)